# How to have only one tile selected at a time in a hex grid in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

as the title says! I'm working on a sort of Civilization type city builder game as practice for the coming school year (only a second year video game programming student!).

I've already gotten a grid generated in game, which looks like:

[This!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL2po.png)

As you can see I've already gotten a rudimentary selection system set up, wherein currently I can only select one tile at a time until I deselect it, then I can select a new tile. The tiles are selected using an OnClick function tied to a collider on the prefab. (will include my code I have currently at the end!)

What I'm wondering how to do is have a tile deselect automatically whenever I select a new tile, so I have only one tile selected at a time.

This is what I have for now for selection.

```
public void OnMouseDown() {
    if (GameManager.Instance.tileSelected == false) {
        if (enabled == false) {
            tileOutlineSprite.SetActive (true);
            enabled = true;
            GameManager.Instance.tileSelected = true;
            this.tileInfo.text = tileType;
        }
    }
    else if (enabled == true) {
        tileOutlineSprite.SetActive (false);
        enabled = false;
        GameManager.Instance.tileSelected = false;
        this.tileInfo.text = " ";
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm currently using to generate my grid! I know it might be a lil messy for now, I'm planning on cleaning it up and refining it as I go on!

```
void generateMap() {
    map = new List<List<TileSelect>>(); //generatign the playing field, making a grid of tile prefabs, and storing their positiosn in a 2d list
    for (int i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
        List <TileSelect> row = new List<TileSelect>();
        for (int j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                iDiff = 0.8f;
            }

            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                iDiff = i + (.2f * (i+1));
            } else if (i != 0) {
                iDiff = i + 0.6f + (.2f * (i+1));
            }
            jDiff = j + (.04f * j);
            int rand = Random.Range (1, 101);
            if (rand <= 45) {
                TileSelect tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate (HeavyForestTile, new Vector3 (iDiff, jDiff, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 ()))).GetComponent<TileSelect> ();
                tile.gridPosition = new Vector2 (i, j);
                tile.tileType = "Heavy Forest";
                tile.GetComponent<TileSelect> ().tileInfo = GameObject.Find ("InfoText").GetComponent<Text>();
                row.Add (tile);
            } else if (rand >= 45 && rand <= 70) {
                TileSelect tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate (LightForestTile, new Vector3 (iDiff, jDiff, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 ()))).GetComponent<TileSelect> ();
                tile.gridPosition = new Vector2 (i, j);
                tile.tileType = "Light Forest";
                tile.GetComponent<TileSelect> ().tileInfo = GameObject.Find ("InfoText").GetComponent<Text>();
                row.Add (tile);
            } else if (rand >= 70 && rand <= 90 ) {
                TileSelect tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate (GrassTile, new Vector3 (iDiff, jDiff, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 ()))).GetComponent<TileSelect> ();
                tile.gridPosition = new Vector2 (i, j);
                tile.tileType = "Grassland";
                tile.GetComponent<TileSelect> ().tileInfo = GameObject.Find ("InfoText").GetComponent<Text>();
                row.Add (tile);
            } else if (rand >= 90 && rand <= 97) {
                TileSelect tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate (GrassRockTile, new Vector3 (iDiff, jDiff, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 ()))).GetComponent<TileSelect> ();
                tile.gridPosition = new Vector2 (i, j);
                tile.tileType = "Light Rocks";
                tile.GetComponent<TileSelect> ().tileInfo = GameObject.Find ("InfoText").GetComponent<Text>();
                row.Add (tile);
            } else if (rand >= 97 && rand <= 100) {
                TileSelect tile = ((GameObject)Instantiate (GrassRock2Tile, new Vector3 (iDiff, jDiff, 0), Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 ()))).GetComponent<TileSelect> ();
                tile.gridPosition = new Vector2 (i, j);
                tile.tileType = "Heavy Rocks";
                tile.GetComponent<TileSelect> ().tileInfo = GameObject.Find ("InfoText").GetComponent<Text>();
                row.Add (tile);
            }

        }

        map.Add(row);
    }
```

Oh! and the game is in 2d if that matters for a solution! Let me know if you need anymore info, I'll happily supply it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to add an additional member to your game manager class:

```
public class GameManager
{
    TileSelect _selectedTile;
    public TileSelect selectedTile
    {
        get { return _selectedTile; }
        set 
        {  
            //unhighlight the previous selected tile
            _selectedTile = value;
            //highlight the newly selected tile
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Include a setter such that everytime you change the selected tile, it unhighlights the selected tile and highlights the new selected tile.

Simply change the selected tile when it is clicked:

```
void onClick(...)
{
    ...
    //on raycast hit with the 2d tile (targetTile)
    gameManager.selectedTile = targetTile;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your answer. While I wasn't able to get it to work myself, I'm sure I would be able to figure it out!

I did however find a somewhat easier solution (for me atleast) located: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/826999/deselect-object-when-another-instance-is-selected.html. Just posting that so if anyone finds this via google search they have an alternative option!